# Sturm-Liouville Equation with Uncommon Weight Function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

In applying a Fourier-series type method to solve a PDE, I've encountered the following ode:

$$a\frac{d^2\phi}{dx^2}+bx\frac{d\phi}{dx}+\lambda\phi=0$$

where $a$ and $b$ are positive constants and $\lambda$ is unknown. This can be put in the standard Sturm-Liouville form

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{x^2/2}\frac{d\phi}{dx}\right)=-\lambda e^{x^2/2}\phi$$

with some straightforward change-of-variables. From this we can conclude the solutions will form an orthogonal basis and that this $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue. However, I can't find any known solutions for this weight function. For $w=e^{-x^2/2}$, we have the Hermite polynomials, but I cannot find any known solutions for $w=e^{x^2/2}$. Does anyone know the name of this class of solution, or any information on how to classify the behavior of the solutions $\phi$?

EDIT: I neglected to mention the domain for this problem is the finite interval $(0,1)$.

EDIT 2: I'm guessing the family of solutions will not be polynomials, since for $\lambda=0$ the solution is the error function. I will also add the solution is subject to a Robin condition at $x=1$ and a Nuemann condition at $x=0$, but these are optional. Only orthogonality on $(0,1)$ is required.

Comment: 1) What is $\lambda$? 2) evaluating the integral of $e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}\phi$ wrt $x$ depends on $\phi(x)$ in general. Try different functions for the latter and see how the solution changes

Comment: @unseen_rider $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue for the eigenfunctions $\phi$. It is determined along with $\phi$. For example, the Hermite polynomials $H_n$ have $\lambda=2n$ for $n\geq0$.

Comment: You **can** consider $\exp(x^2/2)$ as a weight function. See https://mysite.du.edu/~jcalvert/math/hermite.htm

Comment: @JeanMarie I have already mentioned $e^{x^2/2}$ is the weight function. As far as I know, the Hermite polynomials have weight $e^{-x^2/2}$, whereas that source as $e^{x^2/2}$.  That source seems to be incorrect. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials

I should also mention the interval in my problem is finite (0,1). I've added that to my question.

Comment: Have you read the document till its 8th line ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I have read the entire document, yes, but I am not sure how it pertains to my case. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I think that the philosphy behind that is that in order to be able to use a weight function that is hugely increasing like $e^{x^2/2}$, you have to "match" them with functions decreasing much more rapidly than it.

Comment: @JeanMarie I see the point you are making, but I don't believe it is applicable here. Since the domain is the finite interval $(0,1)$, $e^{x^2/2}$ is actually order unity over the entire integration domain.